# AVAssetWriter real-time processing audio from file and audio from AVCaptureSession

Tags: audio, real-time, duration, quicktime, avassetwriter

I'm trying to create a MOV file with two audio tracks and one video track, and I'm trying to do so without AVAssetExportSession or AVComposition, as I want to have the resultant file ready almost immediately after the AVCaptureSession ends. An export after the capture session may only take a few seconds, but not in the case of a 5 minute capture session. This looks like it should be possible, but I feel like I'm just a step away:

There's source #1 - video and audio recorded via AVCaptureSession (handled via AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureAudioDataOutput).

There's source #2 - an audio file read in with an AVAssetReader. Here I use an AVAssetWriterInput and requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue. I call setTimeRange on its AVAssetReader, from CMTimeZero to the duration of the asset, and this shows correctly as 27 seconds when logged out.

I have each of the three inputs working on a queue of its own, and all three are concurrent. Logging shows that they're all handling sample buffers - none appear to be lagging behind or stuck in a queue that isn't processing.

The important point is that the audio file works on its own, using all the same AVAssetWriter code. If I set my AVAssetWriter to output a WAVE file and refrain from adding the writer inputs from #1 (the capture session), I finish my writer session when the audio-from-file samples are depleted. The audio file reports as being of a certain size, and it plays back correctly.

With all three writer inputs added, and the file type set to AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, the requestMediaDataOnQueue process for the audio-from-file still appears to read the same data. The resultant mov file shows three tracks, two audio, one video, and the duration of the captured audio and video are not identical in length but they've obviously worked, and the video plays back with both intact. The third track (the second audio track), however, shows a duration of zero.

Does anyone know if this whole solution is possible, and why the duration of the from-file audio track is zero when it's in a MOV file? If there was a clear way for me to mix the two audio tracks I would, but for one, AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput takes two AVAssetTracks, and I essentially want to mix an AVAssetTrack with captured audio, and they aren't managed or read in the same way.

I'd also considered that the QuickTime Movie won't accept certain audio formats, but I'm making a point of passing the same output settings dictionary to both audio AVAssetWriterInputs, and the captured audio does play and report its duration (and the from-file audio plays when in a WAV file with those same output settings), so I don't think this is an issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the reason for this is:

I correctly use the Presentation Time Stamp of the incoming capture session data (I use the PTS of the video data at the moment) to begin a writer session (startSessionAtSourceTime), and that meant that the timestamp of the audio data read from file had the wrong timestamp - outwith the time range that was dictated to the AVAssetWriter session. So I had to further process the data from the audio file, changing its timing information by using CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming.

```
CMTime bufferDuration = CMSampleBufferGetOutputDuration(nextBuffer);
CMSampleBufferRef timeAdjustedBuffer;
CMSampleTimingInfo timingInfo;
timingInfo.duration = bufferDuration;
timingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = _presentationTimeUsedToStartSession;
timingInfo.decodeTimeStamp = kCMTimeInvalid;

CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(kCFAllocatorDefault, nextBuffer, 1, &timingInfo, &timeAdjustedBuffer);
```

Comment: But isn't that making your audio PTS sBuffers having ALL the same pts (_presentationTimeUsedToStartSession)  ? each an every new audio buffer will have the same PTS no? shouldn't it be increasing?